# Block Matrix Upper Triangular Transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

Let $a,b,c,d$ by real matrices such that the block matrix
$$
A = \begin{bmatrix}
a & b \\
c & d \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
makes sense. Is there a standard similarity transformation $S$ for which
$$
S A S^{-1} = \begin{bmatrix}
e & f \\
0 & g \\
\end{bmatrix},
$$
for some matrices $e,f,g$ with appropriate dimensions that everything makes sense?

Comment: Are you asking for formulas for $e$, $f$, and $g$ or are you asking if $e$, $f$, and $g$ are guaranteed to exist?

Comment: First of all, there is no such $S$ that can be chosen independently of $A$.  Second of all, we generally only guarantee that something like this might happen if we allow for matrices with  complex entries.

Comment: @BrianFitzpatrick Both. If no such $e$, $f$, and $g$ are guaranteed to exist, in general, then the purpose of my question becomes moot.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom $S$ is allowed to have entries which are functions of the entries of $A$.

Comment: $A$ would need to have an $A$-invariant subspace of the appropriate dimension. Not an answer, but the Schur decomposition guarantees the existence of a unitary $Q$ and an upper triangular $T$ such that $A= QTQ^*$.

Comment: More generally, this can be done for a $k \times k$ block $a$ if and only if $A$ has $k$-dimensional invariant subspace.